# No npm scripts works from react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, packaging

I have a React application, that has been working fine for a long time suddenly none of the npm commands in the package.JSON file works.

```
{


 "name": "fitness-appication-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-chat-ui": "^0.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

whenever i try to run a npm command nothing happens in the terminal it just returns blank like such

```
kristoffer@kristoffer-ThinkPad-T570:~/Skrivebord/Fitness-Application/fitness-application-frontend$ npm start
kristoffer@kristoffer-ThinkPad-T570:~/Skrivebord/Fitness-Application/fitness-application-frontend$
```

Is anybody familiar with this issue?

It only happens when i try to run these commands, the built in ones, like `npm install`works fine enough.

output of `npm start run -dd`

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'start', '-dd' ]
npm info using npm@3.5.2
npm info using node@v8.10.0
npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
npm info lifecycle fitness-appication-frontend@0.1.0~prestart: fitness-appication-frontend@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle fitness-appication-frontend@0.1.0~start: fitness-appication-frontend@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle fitness-appication-frontend@0.1.0~poststart: fitness-appication-frontend@0.1.0
npm verb exit
```

Comment: Check the .npmrc file (if exists) for the loglevel variable

Comment: it just specifies `ignore-scripts=true`, could this have an effect?

Comment: Try running `npm start -dd` to see logs i.e. verbose mode. See what it gives you.

Comment: I have edited the post with the outcome of the command @jsbisht.. not sure if it is of much help

Comment: can you share the project through sandbox or other ...? Did you try to remove node_modules folder and npm install again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because you have

```
ignore-scripts=true
```

From docs:

> ignore-scripts
>
> Default: false
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If true, npm does not run scripts specified in package.json files.

Check this [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#ignore-scripts)

P.S. You may use `git log <branch name>` to check when this change was done